# Animating blender model using three.js

Tags: animation, three.js, blender

I'm trying to animate a model exported from blender using three.js. I export the model using the three.js export script for blender and export the whole geometry, I select skeletal animations: Pose, embed animations, scene, hierarchy and export textures. In the js file I load the model using ObjectLoad. When I try to animate the model, I receive an error: "can not bind to bones as node does not have a skeleton" even though the model clearly has a skeleton.

Here's the function I use to add the model to the scene:

```
function addModelToScene(object) {

    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xff0000,
        specular: 0x111111,
        shininess: 50,
        morphTargets: true
    });
    material.skinning = true;
    object.scale.x = object.scale.y = object.scale.z = 3;
    object.rotation.y += Math.PI / 1;
    object.rotation.x += Math.PI / 2;
    object.rotation.z += Math.PI / 1;

    object.traverse(function(child) {
        if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
            child.material = material;
            animation = child.geometry.animations[0];
            mixer.clipAction(animation, child).play();
        }
    });

    mixer.clipAction(animation).play();

    scene.add(object);
}
```

Full jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/48toj4rf/2/ (may take a while to load)

I am using the latest versions of both three.js and blender.